# Stop thread using volatile

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

I'm facing a problem with stopping some threads I'm creating.

The code

```
private volatile int status = STOPPED;

@Override
public void run() {

logger.info("Thread with ID : " + id);
status = RUNNING;
while (status == RUNNING) {                
    try {
        execute();      //<-- very intensive 
        status = IDLE;
        Thread.sleep(DYNAMIC_VALUE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.info("An exception occured in thread with ID : " + id);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(status == IDLE)
            status = RUNNING;
    }
}

    logger.info("Thread with ID : " + id + " just exited.");
}

@Override
public void stop() {
    status = STOPPED;
    logger.info("Thread with ID: " + id + " is stopped.");
}
```

Sometimes when I'm calling `stop()` not all of the threads are stopping. 
This is never called

```
logger.info("Thread with ID : " + id + " just exited.");
```

Instead a logging message inside `execute()` appears repeatedly, thus it doesn't get 
stuck somewhere along the way. It's like the value of `status` doesn't change.

The execute() method is heavyweight. It does a lot of things like updating 
the database and calling web services.

Do you see anything wrong with the way I'm stopping the threads or should I look
deeper? Do I have this aspect covered?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the threads are still `execute()`-ing they won't stop since you set their state to IDLE just afterwards, ignoring the previous value. And even adding a check before `status = IDLE` won't work in all cases.

I suggest to use an `AtomicInteger` instead of a volatile int and use its `compareAndSet` method, i.e.:

```
    while (status.get() == RUNNING) {                
        try {
            execute();      //<-- very intensive 
            if (!status.compareAndSet(RUNNING, IDLE))
                break;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.info("An exception occured in thread with ID : " + id);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(DYNAMIC_VALUE);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            if (!status.compareAndSet(IDLE, RUNNING))
                break;
        }
    }
```

You should also interrupt the thread after setting its status to STOPPED to interrupt the `sleep` if applicable.

Comment: +1 You could also make `status` an `enum` and use `AtomicReference`. That doesn't change the threading concerns, just makes `status` more type-safe and Java-idiomatic. :)

Comment: Damn, I missed that. Thanks you provided more than I asked for. Upvoted and accepted.

Answer (score 8):

I suggest using `Thread#interrupt()` instead of the dual role you have for the `status` flag now (both to *control* the thread and to *report* the status). This is a perfect match for your `Thread.sleep()` call, it will automatically throw an `InterruptedException`.

If you do that, you don't have to change anything in the way your `status` flag is functioning in its *reporting* role—and you can remove any mention of it in `stop()`.

A bonus of this approach is that you will also be able to add a quick `Thread#interrupted` check here and there inside the code behind `execute`, thus making your threads stop even faster; alternatively allowing you to do much more work at once before going to `sleep`. Eliminating `sleep` altogether would then become yet another interesting option.

#### If `interrupt` isn't an option

If you find a good reason why the interruption mechanism won't work for you, then I would advise something less sophisticated than an `AtomicInteger`, but just as effective and arguably cleaner: keep the good design idea to let `status` *report* status (you could demote it to just `boolean` and call it `active`), and create a *separate* `boolean` for the `running` control.

Comment: I thought about using interrupt(), but what if a thread is stuck waiting for a web service to respond. I don't want it to immediately exit, I want to complete the full cycle first and then exit. Your thoughts? Oh and of course upvoted. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You would have to check if your I/O is interruptible---for example, `java.io` isn't and with Java NIO I think there is actually choice of both. If you find it interruptible, then you will have to stay with your current manual model. In that case, however, I would advise something less sophisticated, but just as effective: keep the good design idea to let `status` *report* status (you could demote it to just `boolean` and call it `active`), and create a *separate* `boolean` for the `running` control.

Comment: Love the design suggestions. I will follow them. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

If execute() is running in a thread while you set status=STOPPED, the thread will, on return from execute(), set status=IDLE, and then the finally-block will set status=RUNNING, and your loop loops.

Answer (score 1):

In finally state, you make it RUNNING, it can cause the problem, when you make it STOPPED before it comes to while condition, it can be RUNNING again.

Answer (score 1):

Using your current design, you could check the value of status just before setting it both in the middle of the try block and also in the middle of the finally block.

Cheers